# For Mac, the library extension name can be anything?

Tags: macos, swig

I'm testing SWIG on Mac.

The default file extension that SWIG on Mac produces is .so file as follows.

```
g++ -arch i386 -bundle -undefined suppress -flat_namespace   
    example.o example_wrap.o    -o libexample.so
```

However, I have no problem with -o libexample.dylib in terms of making and running the result.

Why is this? For Mac, the library extension name can be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is the internal Mach-O object file type rather than the file name or extension.  See, for instance, the explanation [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2004/Apr/msg01400.html).